# Youtube埋め込みタグで関連動画非表示のための rel=0 が効かない

Tags: html, youtube

お力をお貸しください。
もしかしたら初歩的なことかもしれませんが
Youtubeの埋め込みタグに関連動画非表示させないための`?rel=0`が効かなくなりました…
以前は効いていたはずなのですが…
なぜか再生後、関連動画が表示されてしまいます。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/154926

Answer (score 3):

[公式ドキュメント](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#rel)によると、

> Note: This parameter is changing on or after September 25, 2018.

とのことで、仕様が変更されたようです。

> After the change, you will not be able to disable related videos.
>   Instead, if the rel parameter is set to 0, related videos will come from the same channel as the video that was just played.

関連動画の表示を止めることは出来無くなりました。代りに、`rel=0` の場合は関連動画が再生中の動画と同じチャンネルから探されるようになります。

Answer (score -2):

日本語だとまだ追記されていないのですね。
関連動画非表示にしなければならず、困っています。

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20595)

Comment: i got it. sorry. i didn't know how to use.